# How can I make a Readonly DateTime picker in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker, readonly

Can anyone know how to make a read-only DateTime picker in VB.NET?

Comment: Don't use a picker. Just write out the date. As the name suggests, a `Picker` is there to _pick_ a different date, so is really for selecting a different value (i.e. **not** read-only).

Comment: SO no chance for readonly datetime picker???

Comment: @Oded i always find this an unhelpful argument. one reason for doing it is if the form is sometimes readonly and sometimes Readwrite and can be toggled between the two. with buttons and textboxes you let the user know via fade/colouring the controls whether he can interact with the control, why wouldn't you want to do the same with a datepicker (with the down arrow disabled/enabled according to state)?

Comment: I try with `Datetimepicker1.Enabled = False`. Its text shows fade.

Comment: Text faded is the accepted state to tell the user they cannot change the value. Your other option is to just use a Label control as suggested by @Oded

Comment: I use a textbox instead of datetime picker and make `Textbox.Text` as `Datetimepicker.Value` and the readonly property of textbox set to true..

Comment: That sounds quite dumb. Why would you do such a thing?

Comment: @WozzeC -- Actually i need just display the date from the database.

Comment: @Thanzeem - then why do you need a DateTimePicker?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway -- The datetime picker is already in the form for adding and editing data. i use the same control for display before delete.

Comment: @WozzeC - I have an app/form that pre-loads time values, and I only want them to be able to change and edit the defaults if they consciously un-check the "OK" box for that particular row. So I want the default state to be one that can't be changed. Sorry if that strikes you as "dumb," but my users are going to mess things up unless I restrict what they can change and when they can change it to small, bite-sized pieces at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to change the `DateTimePicker` control to read-only.  You could probably create your own custom read-only control that either contains or inherits the `DateTimePicker` control, however, you have several other much simpler options:

- If you never need the value to be editable, and it is only ever read-only, then don't use the `DateTimePicker` control.  You should, instead, use a `Label` control.
- If it's sometimes editable and sometimes read-only, use the `DateTimePicker` control and just toggle the `Enabled` property to switch it between editable and read-only modes.
- If you want it to look like other entry controls, but not be grayed-out (as is the case when you disable it), then use a `TextBox` control and set it's `ReadOnly` property to `True`.

Comment: Question - which part gets the "enabled" feature toggled? The whole control is contained in a <div class="input-group date" {etc}>.  The actual form field that contains the entry is <input type="text" {etc}>, and then there is the <span class="input-group-addon"> and <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time">

Comment: @PoloHoleSet what you are describing is an HTML entry field, not a .NET control. This question was in regards to the WinForm control.

Comment: Ah..... the identically named bootstrap function/add-on put me off course.  The "readonly" was what worked for me when applied to the input text field, FYI.